# Visual Studio 2017 не работает режим отладки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, отладка

Проблема в следующем.
При запуске проекта через

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IIS работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если запускаешь проект через режим отладки то результат такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если ты пытаешься зарегиться или войти выдаёт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять почему??? вот файл Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

Вот appsiting.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=aspLaboratory56;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Вот Startup

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

В чём может быть причина? В режиме IIS всё работает!

Вот launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58730/",
      "sslPort": 44388
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44388/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Laboratory56": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58731/"
    }
  }
}
```

Вспомнил ещё одну вещь. Когда не помню, но начал ругаться на ILogger
Нашёл решение

```
// если выдаёт вот такое

        // (InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Laboratory56.Controllers.AccountController'.) 

        // Нужно сделать так, вместо ILogger logger сделать ILoggerFactory logger
        // а вместо  _logger = logger; сделать так  _logger = logger.CreateLogger("My logger");
```

До конца не понял почему но это работает. Может прольёт свет!

Вот проект. Может так понятней будет.
git clone https://EugeneTM@bitbucket.org/EugeneTM/laba.git

Comment: У меня было что то подобное, была проблема в SSL, изначально проект почему то запускался на `http://`, когда сайт с авторизацией работает по `https://`. Все `http://` запросы он отвергал, а не редиректил. Решал тупо написав в адресной строке `https://`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ попробую! Спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не, не работает!

Comment: Второй вариант запускает проект на сервере Kestrel и поэтому для того что бы понять что не так нужно смотреть его настройки в файле launchSettings.json.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Добавил launchSettings.json.

Comment: Систему контроля версий (скажем, git), судя по всему, не используете? Значит, пора начать. Тогда бы вы могли посмотреть предыдущий код, который ещё работал и сравнить отличия с текущим. И легко определить причину.

Comment: Что могу предложить: создайте проект такого же типа с нуля, убедитесь, что отладка работает при нужном типе запуска, потом сравните его настройки с настройками текущего проекта, определите разницу.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Git использую! Не додумался там посмотреть! Да, так пробовал сравнивать и разница только в строке подключения. Было  так `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb` стало `.\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Обновил вопрос! Вспомнил ещё одну вещь! Может поможет!

Comment: Забрал ваш проект, убрал из HomeController/Index код работы с базой (которой у меня нет), запустил, кликнул по Register - показалась форма регистрации. Запустите под отладкой и ловите конкретное исключение, а то сейчас непонятно, в какой момент и что у вас не работает. Даже на скринах в вопросе - разные действия приведены в качестве примеров (регистрация vs профиль)

Comment: @PashaPash не работает в момент залогинеться. При регистрации тоже вылетает страница недоступна. И когда пытаешься зайти под логином. Как только нажимаешь на кнопку то переходит на , (страница недоступна) когда регишься тоже самое.

Comment: @EugeneTM что значит "не рабоает"? Вы же разработчик, а не пользователь. У вас есть отладчик (Visual Studio, запуск по F5), у вас есть вывод в консоль asp.net core - посмотрите, что происходит в приложении в момент неработанья.

Comment: @PashaPash Если бы я всё не попробовал,  я сюда и не писал бы наверное. А, раз я написал, значит не могу понять что не работает. Это же вроде очевидно? Нет?

Comment: Ну раз вы пробовали - у вас должен быть результат попыток? Что-то же происходит с отладчике или в консоли при нажатии на ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

У вас немного сбивающий с толку заголовок. Очевидно же, что приложение у вас работает, отладка работает, просто вы в рантайме получаете исключение

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Laboratory56.Controllers.AccountController'.

Исключение вызвано тем, что вы пытаетесь получить нетипизированный логгер, а стандартная система логгирования регистрирует в DI только типизированный, ILogger

Т.е у вас сейчас конструктор `AccountController` выглядит примерно так:

```
public AccountController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    ILogger logger)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

А должен выглядеть вот так (как в шаблоне .NET Core 2.0):

```
public AccountController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    ILogger<AccountController> logger) // <---------
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

В IIS у вас работает, потому что там вы уже залогинены, и ссылка ведет на другое действие.

Comment: Да, вы правы! Но я пока ждал решение! Уже так сделал!!! Но увы результат тот же.

Comment: @EugeneTM и ошибка та же самая, и в ней упомянут просто ILogger, а не ILogger<t>? Тогда приведите в вопросе минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы - такой, который любой мог бы скопировать и получить ту же ошибку локально. Потому что иначе это будет просто гадание.

Comment: Я могу ссылку на репо дать с этим проектом если это поможет.

Comment: Не знаю здесь это не запрещено?

Comment: Как привести минимальный код, что бы любой мог воспроизвести ошибку, я не знаю. Так как не знаю из за чего это происходить, а ошибки которые я знаю всё написал в вопрос. В общем кинул ссылку на проект. Возможно посмотрев проект и запустив у себя найдётся и проблема.